# PHP Как убрать элемент с страницы после отправки формы

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, request

Все элементы у меня выводятся из бд. 
Пример:

```
if (isset($_POST['sent'])) {
  // Удаляю запись из бд
}
echo '
<form method="POST">
  <div>'.$data['id'].'</div>
  <button name="sent">Sent</button>
</form>
';
```

выполняется перезагрузка страницы, но элемент все еще остается на странице. Мне приходится повторно зайти на это страницу, что бы элемент пропал. Не уже ли нельзя это сделать кроме технологий Ajax?

Comment: у вас мало вводных - что именно вы хотите сделать? По коду создается впечатление, что удаление из БД происходит сразу перед формированием новой страницы, видимо запрос к БД на получение данных происходит до удаления, в таком случае проблема просто в формировании порядка запросов к БД.

Answer (score 0):

Управление DOM возможно только с помощью JS. PHP генерирует код на стороне сервера, поэтому нужно перезагружать страницу. Но отправлять данные на сервер нужно аяксом.

Вот пример на JS

```js
function showForm() {
  document.querySelector('#form').style.display='block';
  document.querySelector('#button').style.display='none';
}

function hideForm() {
  document.querySelector('#form').style.display='none';
  document.querySelector('#button').style.display='block';
}
```

```css
form{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="hideForm();return false" id="form">
  <div>Your information</div>
  <button name="sent" type="submit">Sent</button>
</form>

<button onclick="showForm()" id="button" style="display: none">show form</div>
```